# Azure Data Studio Machine Learning - Python and R Packages not being recognized

Tags: sql-server-2019, azure-data-studio

I'm setting up Azure Data Studio ( ADS ) 1.29 running the Machine Learning extension , to manage SQL 2019 Machine Learning Services in Win2016. The reason for running ADS is so I can install Python and R packages into SQL MLS via ADS. Ultimately we will use this against an Azure SQL Managed Instance ( MI ).

I have configured the default Python and R directories installed by SQL 2019 MLS on the server, as my Python and R machine learning paths in Settings\Extensions\Machine Learning.

When I go to the ADS Machine learning extension and click on "Manage Packages" I get these errors which I cant resolve :

```
"the following R packages are required to be installed vctrs, odbc , sqlmlutils"
```

These R packages are confirmed installed in SQL server.
Not sure how you check if they are installed in ADS?

```
"the following python packages are required to be installed sqlmlutils==1.0.3"
```

These Python packages are confirmed installed in both ADS and SQL server.

```
"Failed to complete task 'Verifying package management dependencies' : Error invalid selection.
```

This error directly above seems to be a result of the first 2 errors.

I have tried reinstalling ADS in new directory etc but this has not worked.

Any assistance appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution :

It appears when you configure ADS it needs this very specific configuration, right down to the .exe name

Machine Learning: Python Path :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\python.exe
```

Machine Learning: R Path :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\bin\R.exe
```

Install this SSL workaround for Python, if needed from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-for-windows/

```
file is   :   Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_1k.msi
```

Also you need to install the odbc and sqlmlutils as per these instructions :

```
https://github.com/microsoft/sqlmlutils/blob/master/R/README.md

Windows

Download the latest release from https://github.com/microsoft/sqlmlutils/releases:

From command prompt in directory where R.exe resides , run

R.exe -e "install.packages('odbc')"
R.exe CMD INSTALL sqlmlutils_1.0.0.zip
```

Once all this installs and runs, you should then be presented with an option to manage both Python and R packages within the Machine Learning extension.

We also found R packages could not be installed in SQL MAnaged Instance or On Prem until you go to ADS version 1.31.0 or higher.